# Haskell Exception: Prelude.Enum.().toEnum: bad argument

Tags: haskell

I have the following code

```
import Data.List

data Card = One
          | Two
          | Three
          | Four
          | Five
          | Six
          | Seven
          | Eight
          | Nine
          | Ten
          | J
          | Q
          | K
          | A
          deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum)

data Hand = Hand Card Card Card Card Card deriving(Show)

largestCard :: Hand -> Card
largestCard (Hand a b c d e) = One
```

However when I try to use `toEnum 3` in GHCi I get `Exception: Prelude.Enum.().toEnum: bad argument`.  How can this be fixed?

The last function is just a dummy function. Right now it does nothing.

Comment: Incidentally most decks of cards don't typically have a card ranked One *and* an Ace.

Comment: Basically thiis should be a Kind type like `II | III | IV | V | VI | VII | VIII | IX | X | J | Q | K | A` and then a Suit type like `D | C | S | H` so a Card type could be `Card Kind Suit`

Answer (score 10):

The type of `toEnum` is

```
toEnum :: Enum a => Int -> a
```

There is no context for GHCi to figure out which `Enum` instance you want in `toEnum 3`, so [by default](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) it supplies the type `()`. That type has only one value, `()`, so anything but `0` will be invalid.

Here are some examples of calling `toEnum` in GHCi:

```
λ> toEnum 0
()
λ> toEnum 1 :: Bool
True
λ> toEnum 3 :: Card
Four
```

You can also use [type applications](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications):

```
λ> :set -XTypeApplications
λ> toEnum @Bool 1
True
λ> toEnum @Card 3
Four
```